# swapping two strings stored in character arrays C

Tags: c

1.C code for swapping two strings stored in character arrays.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Swaps strings by swapping pointers */
void swap1(char **str1_ptr, char **str2_ptr)
{
   char *temp = *str1_ptr;
   *str1_ptr = *str2_ptr;
   *str2_ptr = temp;
}  

int main()
{
  char str1[10] = "geeks";
  char str2[10] = "forgeeks";
  swap1(&str1, &str2);
  printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

2.C code for swapping two strings stored in read only memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Swaps strings by swapping pointers */
void swap1(char **str1_ptr, char **str2_ptr)
{
  char *temp = *str1_ptr;
  *str1_ptr = *str2_ptr;
  *str2_ptr = temp;
}  


int main()
{
  char *str1 = "geeks";
  char *str2 = "forgeeks";
  swap1(&str1, &str2);
  printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

These two are codes for swapping two strings (one string stored in stack,other in read only memory).
Will they work the same?
It is said that first code will not work properly.
If so, Why?

Comment: 'cause the first code is using arrays, that can decay to pointers, but they aren't pointers...

Comment: Your title is missleading. You don't swap "strings" (aka array contents), but pointers. And C does not enforce using a stack or define the location a variable is stored.

Comment: @Gerhard: No, they don't!

Comment: Compiler warnings are not for fun! The compiler should warn about the first code. Pay heed to them. First resolve the warnings, then ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example will not work because you are not really passing pointers to pointers in the call to the `swap1` function, you are passing pointers to arrays.

The type of the expression `&str1` is not `char**`, it is `char (*)[10]`. It is a very big difference, and that will lead to all kind of problems when attempting to dereference those pointers and swap them.